# jQuery Tools Tooltip broken with jQuery 1.8.1

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tools

I had jQuery Tools Tooltips working with jQuery 1.7.1.  However, I had to update my jQuery to 1.8.1 to address a sweet IE8 and lower problem.  The tooltips no longer work with jQuery 1.8.1.  Anyone know a quick fix?  Thanks.

Update - here is the JS I use to call the plugin.  Also using livequery.

```
$(function() {

    $("th a[title], a.tipin[title]").livequery(function(){
        $(this).tooltip({
            offset: [-30, 0],
            opacity: 0.9
        }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down' } });
    });

    $("a.tip[title]").livequery(function(){
        $(this).tooltip({
            offset: [0, 30],
            position: 'center right',
            opacity: 0.9
        }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down' } });
    });});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting ?

Comment: The quickest fix is to just walk away from jQuery Tools.  There are loads of other jQuery plugins that do this better.

Comment: Not getting any JS errors in the console.

Comment: I started using pure CSS tooltips a while ago and I can't imagine a scenario in which I'll go back... Worth looking into unless you need to use js for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was also using jQueryUI 1.8.19 for some other functionality.  I updated jQueryUI to 1.9.1 to play around with its tooltip functions and this fixed my problem with jQuery Tools Tooltips.  I guess there was some kind of conflict in jQueryUI 1.8?

Comment: Who knows?  Regardless, I'd be concerned about using jQuery Tools for the long term.  It's one of the most poorly managed and maintained projects I've seen.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the Tool Tips from jQueryUI instead?  It's very odd that you're using both jQuery Tools and jQueryUI together.  The former was marketed as a replacement for the latter.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably go to jQueryUI for tooltips soon, but I believe they just added tooltips in 1.9 right?

Comment: I don't use either of these "all-in-one" solutions, just write my own or find & integrate specific plugins.  However, I did spend a few days with jQuery Tools and my curiosity quickly turned to frustration and hatred.  As far as your question about Tool Tips recently added to jQueryUI... I'm not sure, but I thought these have been part of it for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with jQuery 1.8 is a change from `outerWidth()` to `outerWidth(true)`. You cannot call the function without a parameter anymore. Set true or false for margins or without margins.

jQuery Tools isn't updated yet, but I changed all calls of `outerWidth` / `outerHight` by myself in the tooltips and now it is working again.

Comment: You can read something more about it here: https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/839 or here: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/