# Get tooltip to work on my actual jquery libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't have JS skills and I want to implement tooltips to my forms.

Actually I could manage to make it works with one of the many released [jQuery libraries (this one to be more specific)](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/form.html).

Problem is that when I add those tooltip libraries, my old jquery functions stop to works (toggle hide/show, etc).
When I remove the new libraries my functions back to work and tooltip obviouslly stop to works.

How could I add ONLY tooltip to my currently JS libraries?

What would be the best approach to achieve the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Please read the FAQ. "What is the best approach to.." isn't a proper question here. If one tooltip plugin isn't working, you could always try one of the many other tooltip plugins out there. I personally prefer the Twitter Bootstrap tooltip.

Comment: In what way do your "old query functions" stop working?  It sounds like the libraries are conflicting with one another.  Any given jQuery plugin shouldn't interfere with the jQuery core.  How are you loading them?  Are there any errors?  How does the code behave?

Comment: Oh and better use the search function next time. Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478277/jquery-tools-tooltip-broken-with-jquery-1-8-1

Comment: @David Conflict is exactly what is happening. I don't know how the code behave nor if there are errors...As I said I have no skills on the jQuery side. How could I get the errors + code behaviour? Thank you.

Comment: @Darkeden: If there are errors they should appear in the debugging console in your browser.  (Chrome developer tools, FireBug, etc.)  You can use those same browser debugging tools to put breakpoints in the code and observe the runtime values/behavior more closely to see what specifically isn't working.  (Basically, on what line of code the observed behavior deviates from the expected behavior.)  You might also try wrapping all of your jQuery code in something like `(function ($) { // your code })(jQuery);` to try to avoid conflicts.  This is called a "closure".

Comment: Thank you David to show me the way...Due to your hint (browser debugging) I could trace and fix an old problem with my site. Tooltip issue is still a problem, but now I believe I'm in the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a plugin for exact this problem: https://github.com/yckart/jquery.tooltip.js

Here's an example, scroll to the last one, there you can find the forms-demo: http://yckart.github.com/jquery.tooltip.js/

Comment: I am going to test it

Comment: @darkeden Okay... If you stuck somewhere, let it me know!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have introduced an error when you use the tooltip library, is there anything in the error console (this would be the first place to look), if so you will need to do some debugging

With jQuery you really dont need a library/plugin to create a tooltip, you just need a few lines of code, just to get you started here is a basic example...

```
jQuery(".toolTipEnable").hover(function(e){
    var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
    jQuery("#toolTip")
        .css({"top":offset.top+40,"left":offset.left+40})
        .text('Tooltip text')
        .show()
},function(e){
    jQuery("#toolTip").hide()
})
```

Where  is an empty div with position absolute

There are many more examples, for instance [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-create-a-tooltips-with-jquery/) that will show you in detail what to do

Comment: Your code alone doesn't make any tooltip appears, but when mixed with this one then works ... $(function() {
      $("#myform :input").tooltip({
      position: "center right",
      offset: [-2, 10],
      effect: "fade",opacity: 0.7
      });
    });